# BLE module supports bit stream TX,RX

Tags: module, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to develop simple BLE system which TX, RX bit stream, not text messaging.
Is there any specific BLE module is able to send/receive bits(like PN random) sequence? 
if not, how this can be possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then all you want is a BLE device with virtual serial port capability. This is very common in BLE and almost every BLE module implements this in some way. A few examples:

[Laird's VSP service](https://assets.lairdtech.com/home/brandworld/files/Application%20Note%20-%20Using%20VSP%20with%20smartBASIC.pdf) (product: BL600, BL652, BT900)

[LSR's Serial-to-BLE Profile](https://www.lsr.com/embedded-wireless-modules/bluetooth-module/sable-x-ble-module/serial-ble-profile) (product: saBLEx)

[TI Serial Communication](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2640_Serial_Communication) (product: CC2640)

[Cypress Custom Serial](http://www.cypress.com/blog/100-projects-100-days/project-020-uart-ble-bridge) (product: PSoc 4 BLE)

I recommend first understanding BLE technology and communication, specifically GATT operations and custom profiles, as this will make it easier for you to pick the right solution to your need.